# DDL statements are not allowed in transactions while reindexing programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am uploading a csv file and reading the content of the file and updating the table to update product Stock, also I need to update the stock to sync in to elastic search and for that I need to run the indexer, so I'm doing that programmatically. Take a look

```
  protected $_indexerFactory;
  public function __construct(\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory)
  {
     $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
  }
  private function reindexAll(){
        $indexerIds = array(
            'catalog_category_product',
            'catalog_product_category',
            'catalog_product_price',
            'catalog_product_attribute',
            'cataloginventory_stock',
            'catalogrule_product',
            'catalogsearch_fulltext',
        );
        
        

        foreach ($indexerIds as $key=> $indexerId) {
            echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
            $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create();
            $indexer->load($indexerId);
            $indexer->reindexAll();
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered my question, I want to answer myself, if anyone else faces this problem trying to accomplish what I was trying, here is your answer. Change your indexer code like this,

```
protected $_indexerFactory;
  public function __construct(\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory)
  {
     $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
  }
  private function reindexAll(){
        $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('cataloginventory_stock');
        $indexer->reindexRow('cataloginventory_stock');

        $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('vsbridge_product_indexer');
        $indexer->reindexAll('vsbridge_product_indexer');
    }
```

The **cataloginventory_stock** indexer will update the inventory in the catalog product grid (admin side) and **vsbridge_product_indexer** indexer will update inventory (stock) at the elastic search.

Comment: I am facing same issue, I tried your solution but it did not work for me

Comment: Can you try to run these two indexers manually
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock vsbridge_product_indexer`
and see if the values are updated, if they are updated then you must be missing something in code